# Signs of model over-fitting

Tags: random-forest, keras

I have created a Random Forest model to predict dataset values. It works all right, but now I'm testing if results can be improved with Keras LSTM.

I don't have much experience with Keras, but I've built a model and made sure to implement variable learning rate.

So now when I run it I see that MAE and RMSE are both very low - considerably lower than in the most accurate version of RF model, but at the same time accuracy is extremely low.

To me it feels like a sign that the model is over-fitting like crazy. Am I correct to assume this based on this limited data?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you judging accuracy to be low?

Comment: It's one of the metrics that keras model is reporting at every epoch.

Comment: Isn’t your model a regression and not a classifier? In other words, is your response variable categorical?

Comment: Yes. And I just realised I've done something dumb - reporting a metric that is meaningless in regression problems.

Comment: Was your accuracy 0%? (Note that Cross Validated generally opposes accuracy and related quantities like sensitivity, specificity, and F1 score as classifier performance metrics, in favor of “proper scoring rules” like MSE (“Brier score” in classification problems) and log loss.)

Comment: @Dave, yes, it was 0.00014.

Comment: Weird...I would expect accuracy to be 0% in a regression problem, but I suppose if you have many values one could have been so dead-on that it was effectively equal (up to the number of decimal places tracked).